# Restrict UIWebView to stay on Facebook page

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, restriction

I need to make a simple UIWebView for iPad, for event when users will login with their accounts and be able to see fixed Facebook public page and be able to scroll this page, comment or like posts but not be able to go to somewhere else except this page. So I am using

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
        NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"http://m.facebook.com/groups/10621329941138"];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Everytime when user end his session hostess will logout from this page to login page. After some experiments I stuck with a few issues:

- At first load I am receiving "The page you requested cannot be displayed right now..." http://uaimage.com/image/5a0cccea
- Logout everytime cause blank white screen (problem with .php?)
- If I will block all links from this page how can I permit logout action a the end of session?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([url.host.lowercaseString rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location == NSNotFound) {

    // Don't go since we're somewhere else now
    return NO;

} else {

    // We can go here
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Same effect as before. I have this "The page you requested...". What can it be?

Comment: It seems I had a capital F, try with lowercase "facebook" and see if that helps...

Comment: Even if this worked it may be fairly unsafe, as any other website could put the keyword "facebook" in its path and it would allow it to proceed with loading.

Comment: in it's host you mean... The problem is Facebook uses external servers to host javascript and other elements, so it's hard to stop the loading... You can also try check the URL only if `navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` to only check if the user initiated the new page load...

Comment: jjv360 looks like you are right, because all my attempts til this moment are unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this before and I would suggest something like

```
return [urlString hasPrefix:@"http://m.facebook.com/"];
```

This is potentially a safer option as well, as it limits to a domain versus simply a keyword check for the word facebook anywhere in the path of the full URL.

You could get a bit more fancy and check for "facebook.com" anywhere after the "http:// and just prior to the second "/".  Can probably also use the baseURL method of the NSURL to help here.

Also, are you absolutely sure you have your UIWebView delegate setup properly?